# Communicate to sh process listening on port

Tags: shell, buffer, overflow, sh

Today, I create trought buffer overflow (don't worry I try it for study reason and not for real attack XD) a sh process that listen on a port of my PC. I create this process with a buffer overflow in my server process and this become a shell. Now, I want to connect from my client to this shell. What can I do for connect to it and send message to this shell for execute command that I send from my client?

I see that server process become a shell by command "netstat -tulpn" that output on my terminal all listening process on my ports.

---

This is my output of `netstat -tulpn` after I create a shell on server process:

```
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:512 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN -
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:513 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN -
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:514 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN -
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:587 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN -
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:79 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN -
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:1745 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 3376/sh
tcp 0 0 127.0.1.1:53 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN -
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:22 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN -
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:631 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN -
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:25 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN -
tcp6 0 0 :::22 :::* LISTEN -
tcp6 0 0 ::1:631 :::* LISTEN -
udp 0 0 0.0.0.0:17730 0.0.0.0:* -
udp 0 0 0.0.0.0:21330 0.0.0.0:* -
udp 0 0 127.0.1.1:53 0.0.0.0:* -
udp 0 0 0.0.0.0:68 0.0.0.0:* -
udp 0 0 0.0.0.0:68 0.0.0.0:* -
udp 0 0 0.0.0.0:35944 0.0.0.0:* -
udp 0 0 0.0.0.0:631 0.0.0.0:* -
udp 0 0 0.0.0.0:5353 0.0.0.0:* -
udp6 0 0 :::17730 :::* -
udp6 0 0 :::3399 :::* -
udp6 0 0 :::56449 :::* -
udp6 0 0 :::5353 :::* -

tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:1745 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 3376/sh
```

In this row there is my process /sh that is the root shell that I create on process server that listen on port 1745.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the classic proof-of-concept attack of just setting up a shell connected directly to a TCP/IP socket, you can connect with netcat:

```
nc hostname portnumber
```

In your case, it looks like you'd use:

```
nc localhost 1745
```

Comment: But in this way on the server side you set the netcat to listen the port in server process. I say that I have a process /sh on my server port(1745) on listening e from my client i try to connect for obtained a shell in the client side for controlling the shell of remote server. I don't use netcat in the server side. I want to connect to remote shell on server, that i already create with buffer overflow shellcode in server process.

Comment: @Alex Ok, I removed the additional information since that seemed to be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

This is my output of `netstat -tulpn` after I create a shell on server process

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:512             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:513             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:514             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:587           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:79              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1745            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3376/sh         
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:17730           0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21330           0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:35944           0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp6       0      0 :::17730                :::*                                -               
udp6       0      0 :::3399                 :::*                                -               
udp6       0      0 :::56449                :::*                                -               
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                -               


tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1745            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3376/sh
```

in this row there is my process /sh that is the root shell that I create on process server that listen on port 1745

Comment: This is not an answer.  You should have edited it into the question.  I've done that for you this time.